# Equivalent definitions of Codimension of closed subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Here I have encountered two definitions of Codimension of closed subset $Z$ of $X$.

1. If $W$ is an irreducible closed subset of $X$, then define $codim(W,X)$ is the supremum of integers $n$ such that there exist a chain: 
   $W = W_{0} < W_{1} <  ...  < W_{n}$  of distinct irreducible closed subset of $X$. Then define $codim(Z,X) = inf_{W \subset Z}codim(W, X)$, where the infimum is taken over all closed irreducible subsets of $Z$
2. Define $codim(Z,X) = inf_{z \in Z}(dim O_{X,z})$.

I have verified these both definitions agree if $X$ is affine scheme, but unable to verify for general scheme. Any suggestion or reference would be helpful.

Comment: A useful fact is that if $Z$ is an irreducible closed subset of $X$ and $U$ is any open subset of $X$ such that $U \cap Z \neq \emptyset $, then $\mathrm{codim} (Z, X) = \mathrm{codim}(Z \cap U, U)$. Try proving this first.

Comment: I proved this using the definition 2. Since one inequality is clear and other inequality follows since $Z \cap U$ is open and dense in $Z$. But how it helps us to prove equivalent of definitions.